# How to Deploy A Smart Contract Using Web3Dart

Tags: flutter, blockchain, solidity, smartcontracts, web3dart

In Javascript We Deploy Smart contract something like that

```
let contract = new web3.eth.Contract(DonactionsAbi);
let deploy = await contract.deploy({ data: DonactionsByteCode, arguments: [address, Name] });
```

I just want to know how to Deploy smart contract in Dart or Flutter

Comment: Were you able to find any solution? @Asad

Comment: yes we can deploy smart contract using web3Dart @AfaqAhmed